# WebService is not seeing DB table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am getting this error when the user clicks on a button to submit data to a table

**Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Bookings'.**

I have ensured that this table exists inside of my database and every other method in my web service is successfully submitting data. I can't figure out what might be the problem.

This is the web service method:

```
public void addBooking(String n, String e, String r, String a1, String a2, String a3, String c, String t, String i)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(@n, @e, @r, @t, @c, @i, @a1, @a2, @a3)";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\n00093500\\Desktop\\MMCA2\\APP_DATA\\NORTHWIND.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = n;//name
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@e", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = e;//email
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@r", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = r;//restaurant
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@t", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = t;//telephone
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = c;//county
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@i", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = i;//info
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@a1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = a1;//address
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@a2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = a2;//address
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@a3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = a3;//address
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This is function that is working fine:

```
public void addMessage(String n, String e, String m)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Messages VALUES(@n, @e, @m)";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\n00093500\\Desktop\\MMCA2\\APP_DATA\\NORTHWIND.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        //change these three lines to use actual database column types
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = n;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@e", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = e;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@m", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = m;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a function that works for comparison?

Comment: Does it have a different schema?

Comment: sure added it to code now

Comment: Are you sure the connectionstring is properly worded? Also, perhaps it would be more efficient if you save the connection string somewhere and call it rather then retyping it for each method.

Comment: @JoeR Nope, It should be within the same scheme

Comment: Are your parameter names the result of obfuscation? :)

Comment: haha, no apologies, It's just because I'm trying to tidy up a college assignment which is due in the next hour and was cutting corners as it where!

Comment: Errors don't usually lie, are you sure that table exists and is the correct name `Booking` instead of `Bookings`???

Comment: No the table is definitely called `Bookings`

Comment: have you tried retrieving the SQL query that is generated and running that in yourself to see if the same error occurs?

Comment: Is this an ASMX web service, or a WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

Make "Bookings" "dbo.Bookings" in case there is another object (view, cell, etc) of the same name in the Db

Comment: Unfortunately no change

Comment: Is it possible that `Bookings` is not in the `dbo` schema?